# Tamarind tree leaves and branches are turning brown all of a sudden

Tags: trees, plant-health, pests, insects

My tamarind tree is around 25 years old and it was all healthy till 3 months back. All of a sudden some of its branches and leaves are turning brown. Tree is full of fruits now and even they are getting dried because of this issue. The bark has some powdery material on it, which I guess is some sort of insects infested it and eating the bark, though Im not very sure. Im attaching the images for your reference. This plant is in our backyard and has been a great plant and helped us a lot. I really want to save this plant. Please help. If you have any solution for this issue, Please try to explain me the steps to be taken to save this plant. Thanks in advance.

Edit: After observing the bark a lil closer, I found termites and round headed borers on the stem. Attached pics. Please let me know If I'm left with any chance of saving the plant. The out bark is getting peeled off.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good question & good illustrations; if could include an illustration of the base of the tree, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks possible that the problem is either at the roots or from that sunken area which has no bark on the trunk, leading down to the part which has whitish deposits. Clear away the debris from the base of the tree and check whether there is any fungal growth very close or nearby to the trunk. Also check whether that sunken area in the trunk (especially at the base) is soft, as well as pushing on the tree to make sure it is stable. It may be rotting from the inside...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable insights. The plant is sturdy when I push it (Its too big actually). I have observed the bark closer and attached pics for the same. It seems like round headed borer has infested it and then termites are eating the dead part. All that Im worried is whether Im left with any options to save the plant.